# Javascript for Acrobat Pro X, simple 3 step and repeat

Tags: javascript, acrobat, flip

I need a simple script compiled for a acrobat pro X plugin.
I need to make one change to every page in a multipage PDF.
A. Select All
B. Flip Horizontal
C. Move to Next Page
D. Go to A, until last page of PDF

Is this something that someone on here could script and post for me?
Much appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

Is this still up to date?

Can be done with javascript for Acrobat, no need for a plugin. (If I get it right ^^)

```
this.setPageRotations(,, 180);
```

This should do what you want.

From JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference:
[Source Link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/JS_API_AcroJS.88.528.html)